# 0x API Tokens Interface (Deprecated?) and Swap Quote

Tags: 0x

The 0x API docs say that the token interface is deprecated, but it seems that it's required to know which tokens are supported. For instance, I cannot send any Token symbol to the quote API, it will return a validation error for an unknown token symbol. Yet, the API docs suggest that other tokens, not listed, may work.
https://0x.org/docs/api#get-swapv1tokens

> Deprecated. Get the tokens with known symbols available for trading in the /swap/v1/quote endpoint. If a token is not returned, it may still be available but not queryable by token symbol.

Can someone please explain how one would use the 0x API for a token *not* on the tokens list?  And, if the tokens list is deprecated, should we anticipate the swap quote interface to be deprecated as well?

Example Quote Request:
https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=ETH&sellAmount=1000000000000000&buyToken=SHIB

```
{"code":100,"reason":"Validation Failed","validationErrors":[{"field":"buyToken","code":1004,"reason":"Could not find token `SHIB`"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the token address in `sellToken` or `buyToken` fields. E.g for ETH->SHIB,
https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=ETH&sellAmount=1000000000000000&buyToken=0x95ad61b0a150d79219dcf64e1e6cc01f0b64c4ce  or
https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee&sellAmount=1000000000000000&buyToken=0x95ad61b0a150d79219dcf64e1e6cc01f0b64c4ce.

The above has always worked but we added a "convenience" layer to specify the symbol. It became a source of confusion as this token list was always a subset of tokens that 0xAPI could find swaps for.

Comment: I tested this and I swear it wasn't working. But really glad it is, thanks!